# MatPlotlib: Patches not being displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have just started experimenting with matplotlib, since I often come across instances where I need to plot some data, for which matplotlib seems an excellent tool. I attempted to adapt the ellipse example in the main site, so as to draw two circles instead, how ever after running the code, I find that none of the patches are displayed, I am not able to figure out what exactly is wrong... here is the code. Thanks in Advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

plt.axis([-3,3,-3,3])
ax = plt.axes([-3,3,-3,3])
# add a circle
art = mpatches.Circle([0,0], radius = 1, color = 'r', axes = ax)

ax.add_artist(art)

#add another circle
art = mpatches.Circle([0,0], radius = 0.1, color = 'b', axes = ax)

ax.add_artist(art)

print ax.patches

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which version of matplotlib are you using? I'm not able to replicate your results, I can see the two ellipsis quite well. I'm going by a long shot, but i guess you mean to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# create the figure and the axis in one shot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(6,6))

art = mpatches.Circle([0,0], radius = 1, color = 'r')
#use add_patch instead, it's more clear what you are doing
ax.add_patch(art)

art = mpatches.Circle([0,0], radius = 0.1, color = 'b')
ax.add_patch(art)

print ax.patches

#set the limit of the axes to -3,3 both on x and y
ax.set_xlim(-3,3)
ax.set_ylim(-3,3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks the changes have made it work, I am using Matplotlib v 1.2.0, compiled from source. Just a question what does the  ax.set_xlim method limit? Again thanks a lot

Comment: The `set_xlim` method impose the limit of your plot in terms of data coordinates. So putting -3,3 as parameters tell to matplotlib to plot only those objects that are included in that interval

Comment: For some reason this throws a syntax error for me: `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?`